# How to trigger a 403 error code (in PHP) and display a custom message?

Tags: php, html, status

I'm trying to set up some basic error handling for my website.

```
http_response_code(403);
die;
```

Will throw a 403 error and stop the page load dead.
It will also result in a default error "page" being shown.
Is there a way to keep the default error screen being loaded and add a customized error message as well?
The custom 403 page listed in .htaccess is not being displayed when I trigger the error this way.

```
http_response_code(403);
die("myErrorMessage");
```

Will display myErrorMessage, but it will not be shown as a 403 error, only the message is echoed on screen.

I would like to keep things tight and tidy, only add the personalized extra message to the standard error screen if possible.

Comment: Http is streaming, as soon as something is echoeded into the screen, HTTP Headers is already being sent, and you can't change it.

Comment: _"but it will not be shown as a 403 error"_ - It will send a 403 http status code to the client and show the message you output. If you send a status code using PHP, then it's your codes responsibility to return the content. If it is the web server that send the status code, then it's the web servers responsibility. Usually, you let your code handle all the requests (having some router etc) and handles the content.

Comment: So, if I want to add any message, I will have to provide the entire page with formatting and everything. :/ Maybe I'll just skip the message all together...

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to handle that? It's better if your application handles anything related to it (including error messages). That way, your app will be way more portable and won't rely on any web server configuration.

Comment: You’re right of course, I expressed myself poorly. I was considering other options of handling the situation in general.